# How do I store images in mysql installed in Ubuntu [C#] ?

Tags: c#, mysql, image, photo

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                          "INSERT INTO IMAGE (ImageNo,Image) VALUES(@ImageNo,@Image)", conn);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(pbxImage.Tag.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] bImage = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(bImage, 0, (int)fs.Length);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageNo",1);            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", bImage);
            fs.Close();
```

I want to create a photo on Ubuntu server and load the photo in Ubuntu into c #.
I can not sense what to do.
I do not know how to load the picture path in Ubuntu into mysql and load the picture in c #. It seems really difficult. Help.

Comment: How about copying the image into a folder and just store the path in your database?

Comment: need to save the image to the server. And I have to load the image on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use BLOB field type to store image data. To write an image to your database, you need to convert image file to a byte array, then use the byte array as a parameter to an `INSERT` query. Note, it is neceessary to configure the server. See [Handling BLOB Data With Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-blob.html) for details.
If your server is MySQL then you have to **use [MySQLCommand](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html) object instead of SqlCommand.** Or it possible by using [ExecuteNonQuery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlhelpermembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlhelper-executenonquery-overloads) method of `MySqlHelper` class.